# Change iTunes click to enqueue instead of play

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, itunes

I'm trying to change the way iTunes works when you click a song or an album. I want to intercept the click and, instead of playing that item, I want that item added to a certain playlist.
I was trying to intercept the clicking event by capturing it from the `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`, stopping it from propagating and execute an Apple Script that would do the addition to the playlist.
Problem is that I can't intercept the iTunes mouse click. Can you help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to go about this would be to create a **SIMBL plugin** which would allow you to get access to iTunes (the application itself) and from there you should be able to method swizzle the action which the play button triggers to your own method which does what you want.

I'd guess from your question that in your method you would execute an Apple Script to add the selected item to a playlist. Here's some more info on doing that with AppleScript: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531692/applescript-question-adding-tracks-to-playlists) and [here](http://www.netstreamshifter.com/2009/08/applescript-to-add-selected-tracks-to.html).

For more info on SIMBL [check out the website](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) and if you're not sure where to start check out [this tutorial](http://www.culater.net/wiki/moin.cgi/CocoaReverseEngineering#head-f1f1d6fd4cfed4ecd0fbf0c5a94cf095928cdfbe) on building a SIMBL plugin.

Comment: I took a look at SIMBL and I think the "Method Swizzling" technique to replace the "Play" function in iTunes is the best option. Still struggling with it, though. :)

Comment: Yeh, it's certainly not easy. The hardest part is to find out the action the play button calls. There's a tool called `class-dump` which might help you out with that. Find more info about it [here](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was already going through the SIMBL tutorials and managed to create an iTunes.h with all the Cocoa functions iTunes uses. I'm now struggling with the Method Swizzling which I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Great! For method swizzling I use this class [here](http://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle), there's some info on that page about how to use it. An example is:`[iTunes jr_swizzle:@selector(play:) withMethod:@selector(my_play:) error:&error];` so that when iTunes calls `play:`, it will instead trigger your method `my_play:`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying right now. I get Xcode to compile the god damn bundle but then I cannot find it.

Comment: How is it going? Have you been able to get method swizzling to work?

Comment: Not yet. I managed to create the bundle, compile it, call the method swizzling function, no error returned. Then I open iTunes, I check the logs and I see my bundle was loaded (I see my messages in the `init` function, before and after the swizzling) but then, when I call the `play pause` function, it works normally, not like I wanted it to in my new method. I have no idea what's happening. Might open a new question here...

Comment: @Joshua let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2661/discussion-between-lamelas-and-joshua)

Answer (score 2):

I have found another way to do this by using the `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` rather than intercepting a click. iTunes posts a distributed notification when the player state is changed, this includes the play button being pressed.

You can subscribe to this notification called `com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo` and when you receive it you can see if the player state is Playing and if so you know the button has been pressed, from here you can run some AppleScript to pause/stop the music playing and do what you want (e.g add the selected song to a playlist).

The notification also provides a lot of other information all of which you can see here:
 [image]

To subscribe to the notification just do the following and implement the `iTunesPlayerStateChanged:` method.

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iTunesPlayerStateChanged:) name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to track the position of the iTunes window/play button using the accessibility APIs and then install an active [`CGEventTap`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventTapCreateForPSN) to intercept mouse clicks. If the click lands on the iTunes button, then you can prevent the event from propagating to iTunes (by returning `NULL` from your event tap callback) and handle it yourself.

The main advantage of this over the SIMBL method is that it doesn't rely on the internal implementation in iTunes, so should continue to work even if iTunes is updated and changes its internal methods/functions.

Comment: Nice answer. I had considered the Accessibility API's in conjunction with `NSEvent`'s `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` to detect a mouse down and then check if it's directed at the play button but knew that there would be no way to prevent it reaching iTunes but I see now that `CGEventTap` can take care of that. +1!

Comment: Would this allow me to intercept clicks made in individual songs or just clicks made on the Play/Pause button? Thank you for your answer! :)